# SQLALchemy getting error when try to find and update atomically datetime fields

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to update atomically one row

my code:

```
class TestModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    col1 = Column(String)
    col2 = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:teste123!@localhost/teste', echo=True)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    TestModel.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    TestModel.metadata.create_all(engine)

    date1 = datetime(2017, 1, 10, 0)
    date2 = datetime(2017, 1, 11, 0)

    t = TestModel()
    t.col1 = "test"
    t.col2 = date1
    session.add(t)
    session.commit()

    # atomically doesn't work
    session.query(TestModel).filter(and_(TestModel.id == 1, TestModel.col2 < date2))\
        .update({TestModel.col2.name: date2})

    # two operation work
    result = session.query(TestModel).filter(and_(TestModel.id == 1, TestModel.col2 < date2)).one()  # works
    if result:
        result.col2 = date2
        session.commit()
```

When I try to do atomically I'm getting error:
**TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes**

I know that my datetime has no timezoneinfo (tzinfo makes code to work), but why second one works and atomically doesn't. I want to avoid use tzinfo always that  I need to update this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my question here:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update.params.synchronize_session

When I try to update, default strategy is 'evaluate', that is, try to update session objects after. I did a condition to update and SQLAlchemy try to execute him. my session has a model with datetime without timezone, and python gets error when try to compare date with tz and w/o

I solve changing strategy to

```
...updates(values=..., synchronize_session=False)
```

I just need to be careful with using my objects in session because it's outdate